# sending curl request twice in a function not working

Tags: php, curl, dictionary

I am sending curl request to freemaptools.com to find zipcode in a radius.My code is below

```
function get_zip_in_radius($lng,$lat,$radius,$a) {
    $headers = array(
                     'Referer:http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm',
                     'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36',
                     'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                     'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5',
                     'Connection:keep-alive',
                     'Pragma:no-cache',
                     'Cache-Control:no-cache',
                     'Origin:http://www.freemaptools.com',
                     'Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8'    
                     );

    $curl_handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.freemaptools.com/ajax/get-all-zip-codes-inside.php?mode=9&radius='.$radius.'&lat='.$lat.'&lng='.$lng.'&rn='.$a);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "__utma=126142042.1539287389.1412828292.1412828292.1412828292.1; __utmb=126142042.1.10.1412828292; __utmc=126142042; __utmz=126142042.1412828292.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1");

    $buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

    $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $body = substr($buffer, $header_size);

    curl_close($curl_handle);

    $body = strtr($body,array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;")); // for     displaying html tags

    function get_string($string, $start, $end){
        $found = array();
        $pos = 0;
        while( true )
            {
                $pos = strpos($string, $start, $pos);
                if ($pos === false) { // Zero is not exactly equal to false...
                    return $found;
                }
                $pos += strlen($start);
                $len = strpos($string, $end, $pos) - $pos;
                $found[] = substr($string, $pos, $len);
            }
    }
    return get_string($body,'zipcode="','"');
}

function get_zip()
{    $post=$this->get_zip_in_radius($value[0]->geometry->location->lng,$value[0]->geometry->location->lat,'50','7623');
    $post2=$this->get_zip_in_radius($value[0]->geometry->location->lng,$value[0]->geometry->location->lat,'100','6542');
}
```

Now my problem is when i am sending request for two radius one for 50KM and other for 100KM only one request sending me response other is not. Can anyone tell me what could be the problem in my code.Please help me. Your help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

value of `$value[0]->geometry->location->lng` and `$value[0]->geometry->location->lat` geting from google API

Comment: If you change the order of the calls in `get_zip`, how does it affect the results?

Comment: only first request sending response.Other one is ignored.

Comment: problem solved!! it was my silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function get_string($string, $start, $end)
{
    $found = array();
    $pos = 0;
    while( true )
        {
            $pos = strpos($string, $start, $pos);
            if ($pos === false) { // Zero is not exactly equal to false...
            return $found;
        }
            $pos += strlen($start);
            $len = strpos($string, $end, $pos) - $pos;
            $found[] = substr($string, $pos, $len);
        }
     return $found;
}

function get_zip_in_radius($lng,$lat,$radius,$a) {
$headers = array(
                 'Referer:http://www.freemaptools.com/find-zip-codes-inside-radius.htm',
                 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.94 Safari/537.36',
                 'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                 'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5',
                 'Connection:keep-alive',
                 'Pragma:no-cache',
                 'Cache-Control:no-cache',
                 'Origin:http://www.freemaptools.com',
                 'Content-Type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8'    
                 );

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.freemaptools.com/ajax/get-all-zip-codes-inside.php?mode=9&radius='.$radius.'&lat='.$lat.'&lng='.$lng.'&rn='.$a);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "__utma=126142042.1539287389.1412828292.1412828292.1412828292.1; __utmb=126142042.1.10.1412828292; __utmc=126142042; __utmz=126142042.1412828292.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmt=1");

$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

$header_size = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$body = substr($buffer, $header_size);

curl_close($curl_handle);

$body = strtr($body,array("<"=>"&lt;","&"=>"&amp;")); // for     displaying html tags


return get_string($body,'zipcode="','"');
}

function get_zip()
{        $post=$this->get_zip_in_radius($value[0]->geometry->location->lng,$value[0]->geometry->location->lat,'50','7623');
    $post2=$this->get_zip_in_radius($value[0]->geometry->location->lng,$value[0]->geometry->location->lat,'100','6542');
}
```

After `get_string()` defining outside the `get_zip_in_radius()` its working fine.